# Parse a single attribute in SQL

Tags: sql, string, parsing, google-bigquery

I have a description attribute which has all the below information.

```
 Subject:
 Security ID:   SXXX 
 Account Name:  GXXX$
 Account Domain: GGGG
 Security ID:   SXXX0
 Account Name: NETWORK 
 Account Domain: AUTHORITY
```

Workstation Name:

I am trying to parse this attribute and get the different parts of it and store it in a separate column. For example, Subject goes into a separate column, Security ID goes into a separate column and so on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? String manipulation functions are often different between the various vendors. What have you tried so far? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The data is stored in Google Big Query. I am using SQL to process it.

Comment: "SQL" has many dialects.

Comment: I tried this query but not returning the results as expected:

SELECT LEFT(NTH(3, SPLIT(path, ':')),10) part3,

       NTH(4, SPLIT(path, ':')) part4,

       NTH(5, SPLIT(path, ':' )) part5,

       NTH(6, SPLIT(path,':')) part6,

       NTH(7, SPLIT(path,':')) part7,

FROM 

(SELECT description as path

FROM MyGeotabDataAgent.EventLogs_20160418 

WHERE id = '4624' and task = "Logon")

Comment: I wonder whether regular expressions will help me !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below as an example of using [Regular expression functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#regularexpressionfunctions) in BigQuery

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(description, 'Subject:([\\s\\S\\w\\W]*?)Security ID:') AS subject,

  REGEXP_EXTRACT(description, 'Security ID:([\\s\\S\\w\\W]*?)Account Name:') AS securityId_1,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(description, 'Account Name:([\\s\\S\\w\\W]*?)Account Domain:') AS accountName_1,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(description, 'Account Domain:([\\s\\S\\w\\W]*?)Security ID:') AS accountDomain_1,

  REGEXP_EXTRACT(description, 'Account Domain:[\\s\\S\\w\\W]*?Security ID:([\\s\\S\\w\\W]*?)Account Name:') AS securityId_2,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(description, 'Security ID:[\\s\\S\\w\\W]*Account Name:([\\s\\S\\w\\W]*?)Account Domain:') AS accountName_2,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(description, 'Account Name:[\\s\\S\\w\\W]*Account Domain:([\\s\\S\\w\\W]*)') AS accountDomain_2,

FROM
  (SELECT ' Subject: Test1
   Security ID:   SXXX 
   Account Name:  GXXX$
   Account Domain: GGGG
   Security ID:   SXXX0
   Account Name: NETWORK 
   Account Domain: AUTHORITY' AS description 
  ),
  (SELECT 'Subject: Test2 Security ID: SXXX Account Name: GXXX$ Account Domain: GGGG Security ID: SXXX0 Account Name: NETWORK Account Domain: AUTHORITY ' AS description)
```